# Creating a HTML5 - Image Editor which uses SVG

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I'm trying to create a simple 'image editor' using HTML5/Javascript that allows to load an image (.png for instance), draw/move/delete different shapes onto that image, and retrieve the coordinates of these shapes drawn to modify the original image.

I've been reading quite a lot regarding SVG and canvas, and my final thought was to go with SVG, as it's handling all the different object states etc. Looking at different examples of code though I'm not sure anymore if SVG is the right way to go...is it even possible to accomplish what I want using SVG?

Update:
The problem is basically to ensure that the chosen strategy (SVG/canvas) supports loading an image, drawing additional shapes, and retrieving the coordinates in a way that modifications on the original image result in the same picture as shown in the editor.

Comment: You can do all that and more with https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit

Comment: @RobertLongson: Thanks, I've seen that part, yes. I'm struggling a bit with the fact that I want to load an image as a base, draw onto the image and receive the coordiantes of the different shapes drawn in a way that I could write them onto the original image on the server.

Comment: you title does not ask any question or state any problem

Comment: The problem here is saving the *coordinates* or is it to create the editor itself? **unclear**..

Comment: In my experience, fabricjs is good for image,text,shape editing